# Micronaut - @Controller vs @Endpoint

Tags: java, microservices, endpoint, micronaut

I don't understand when I should use `@Controller` and when `@Endpoint` to create an endpoint with Micronaut framework.

Following the [documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#quickStart) I created a service and made it available at `/endpoint` this way:

```
@Controller("/endpoint") 
public class DummyService {
    @Get 
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 
    public String index() {
        return "Hello World!"; 
    }
}
```

But [here](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#buildingEndpoints) it's created with the `@Endpoint` annotation instead:

```
@Endpoint("/endpoint") 
public class DummyService {
    @Get 
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) 
    public String index() {
        return "Hello World!"; 
    }
}
```

**Which is the proper way to create a service and make it available at an endpoint in Micronaut?** 
If this question arises from a lack of understanding of more basic concepts, could you provide me with references?

Comment: The `@Endpoint` is used for monitoring/management (judging from the section it is specified in) and thus is treated specially. Whereas the `@Controller` is a regular rest service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Endpoint` is supposed to be used for management endpoints (adjusting log levels, managing caches, monitoring resource utilization, etc), not application functionality.  `@Controller` should be used for application endpoints that are not part of management and monitoring.

**EDIT**

To address the question specifically asked:

> Which is the proper way to create a service and make it available at an endpoint in Micronaut?

In general, the way to do that is to add a bean to the application context that is your service, and then let the DI container inject that bean wherever is needed.

```
@Singleton
public class SomeService {
    // ...
}

@Controller
public class SomeController {
    private final SomeService someService;

    public SomeController(SomeService someService) {
        this.someService = someService;
    }

    // ...
}

@Endpoint
public class SomeManagementEndpoint {
    private final SomeService someService;

    public SomeManagementEndpoint(SomeService someService) {
        this.someService = someService;
    }

    // ...
}
```